# How to convert testng xml results to html?

Tags: java, testng

I got a testng test results xml file from a source. I have to convert it into html report, but could not find a way to do it. I tried this free online converter, but it does not work. It keeps the xml file in html format. https://www.aconvert.com/document/xml-to-html/

How do I do the conversion ?

Thanks.

Comment: HTML reports are generated by default . There should be a `index.html` report in `test-output` folder. Open that report in browser. Or Are you trying to add a custom html report  to your project?

Comment: @user1207289 - The test result xml was given to me. It was not the result of a local execution. The xml file from the original location is over written now. Otherwise I could have picked up the html report also directly from the location.